# How to find the div which is currently at the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My HTML page contains multiple div elements one below the other. The basic layout of the page is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        xyz
    </title>
    <link id="font" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&amp;text=" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body class="fullscreen">
    <div id="surveyform">
        <div class="form">
            <ul class="questions">
                <li class="group connected" id="q1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item">
                            <span> 1 </span>
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <span>Developer Intern</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="description">
                                Random Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="group connected" id="q2">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item">
                            <span> 2 </span>
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <span>Developer Intern</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="description">
                                Random Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="group connected" id="q3">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item">
                            <span> 3 </span>
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <span>Developer Intern</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="description">
                                Random Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="group connected" id="q4">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item">
                            <span> 4 </span>
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <span>Developer Intern</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="description">
                                Random Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="group connected" id="q5">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item">
                            <span> 5 </span>
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <span>Developer Intern</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="description">
                                Random Text
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

there can be 100's of such div. But i want to perform a specific action on the div which is currently in the center of the screen.

One way of doing this can be using the offset function.

What is the best way to find the div currently at the center of the screen?

Comment: can there be multiple div in screen?

Comment: Please show what you tried using offset

Comment: Could try using [elemetFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) and some simple window calcs but probably need to use a fallback in case it isn't one of your tartgets depending on how layout works

Comment: Coud you please show your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:in-viewport` selector provided by the [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) jQuery plugin to select all currently visible divs. Then you can pick the middle one (it should be close to the center of the screen) and interact with it.

See the demo in the snippet below.

```js
function highlightDivInTheMiddle() {
  var divs = $(".divs > div:in-viewport");
  var middleDiv = divs[Math.floor(divs.length / 2)];
  $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
  $(middleDiv).addClass('highlighted');
}
```

```css
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.divs > div {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.divs > .highlighted {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport/master/lib/isInViewport.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="highlightDivInTheMiddle()">Highlight div in the middle</button>

<div class="divs">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```